# Error when printing

Tags: java

I get an error when printing. Could you tell what's the problem in the code? Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void doStuff(int a, int b){
        for(int i = a; i <= b; i++){
            printNum(i);
        }
    }

    public static void printNum(int x){
        System.out.print(x + " "); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(doStuff(2, 7));
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(doStuff(2, 7));` this is your problem.  `doStuff(2, 7)` is a void method that doesn't return anything (so it can't be printed).  Remove the `system.out.println` in front of it.

Comment: It would help a great deal if you indicated what error message you're seeing. Also, why do you have `System.out.println(doStuff(2, 7))`? `doStuff` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `doStuff` returns void and you try to print it
(by using it as an argument to `System.out.println`).